# C preprocessor __COUNTER__ alternative

Tags: c, enums, macros, c-preprocessor

I currently have a system where I have an enum and an array that holds the enum values as strings. The enum and array is generated via a macro and the actual value of the enum entrys encode 3 bits of information additionally to their number.

myEnum_def.h

```
// args can be be -3 <= args <= 3
// so depending on the input value it is encoded as |29 enum entry bits|arg sign bit|2 arg value bits|
#define ENCODE_ARG(args) (((((args) & ((unsigned int)-1)) >> ((sizeof(unsigned int) * 8) - 1)) * (1 << 2)) | (3 & args))
#define MAKE_ENUM_VALUE(name, args) name = ((__COUNTER__ << 3) | MAKE_BYTECODE_ARGS(args))

#define MAKE_TEXT(name) #name
#define MAKE_NAME(name, args) MAKE_TEXT(name)

#define MY_ENUM_DEFINITIONS(M) \
    M(myValue1, -2), \
    M(myValue2, 2), \
    ...
    M(myValueN, 1)
```

myEnum_undef.h

```
#undef MY_ENUM_DEFINITIONS

#undef MAKE_NAME
#undef MAKE_TEXT

#undef MAKE_ENUM_VALUE
#undef ENCODE_ARG
```

myEnum.h

```
#ifndef MYENUM_H
#define MYENUM_H

#include "myEnum_def.h"

enum myEnum {
    MY_ENUM_DEFINITIONS(MAKE_ENUM_VALUE),
    MY_ENUM_COUNT = __COUNTER__,
}

extern const char * myEnum_names[];

#include "myEnum_undef.h"

#endif
```

myEnum.c

```
#include "myEnum.h"
#include "myEnum_def.h"

const char * myEnum_names[] = {
    MY_ENUM_DEFINITIONS(MAKE_NAME)
}
```

This works exactly like I want it but it is using the __ COUNTER __ macro and assumes that the macro starts always at 0. I tried to use the #line directive instead but it expands all enum entrys to the same value. What I need is a way to start a new counter or reset the __ COUNTER __ macro when myEnum.h is processed.

Comment: The macro [does always start at `0`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html)? What is the problem?

Comment: If I have a file main.c with `#include "myEnum1.h" #include"myEnum2.h"` the macro is does not reset and the enum entry value bits in MyEnum2 don't start at 0.

Comment: Why do you care about the values if you want the to be unique, that will be achieved regardless of whether or not the macre resets! It's used to generate unique values. If you do care about the values then it's not going to work that way, but `enum`s do start at `0` by default, so I don't see the point now because without the assignment it would work just as you expect.

Comment: What's the advantage of having the args encoded in the enumerated value? Why not create an array that holds the args data alongside the array that stores the enum names? Then you could use a regular, no-frills (and no-counters) X macro. And it would also save you some bit-shifting when you want to get at the enumerated value.

Comment: Oh man, sometimes you just want to be too clever. That's it I will just make another array for the args. Thanks, should I delete the question?